# Quickly replace int with enum values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

I'm trying to replace some magic int numbers with (existing) enum values. There are a lot of occurrences so I wonder if there is a shortcut or addon that speeds up this process.

Example:

```cs
int myType;
//...
myType = 2;
```

There's an enum for this type:

```cs
enum MyEnum
{
    TypeA = 1,
    TypeB = 2,
    //...
}
```

At the end, this is what I want to achieve:

```cs
MyEnum myType;
//...
myType = MyEnum.TypeB;
```

I can do this manually, no problem. But then I always have to search for the correct value in my enum, copy/paste the value, etc. It just takes quite long.

Is there a Visual Studio / Resharper shortcut or Addon that can speed up this process?

---

**EDIT:** I don't need a completely automated process. Just a good way to speed up this process.

Especially this part:

```cs
MyEnum myType = (MyEnum) 2;
```

Is there no tool that replaces the `(MyEnum) 2` with `MyEnum.TypeB`?

My ideal workflow would be something like this: Change the type of `myType` to `MyEnum` and then *magically* replace any known int values to their corresponding enums.

Comment: I can't see how an automated tool could differentiate between a number that should be converted to the enum, and an identical number that should not...

Comment: You could just replace `myType = 2;` with `myType = (TypeA) 2;` which will keep old values untouched and new code would be strongly typed. This may be a quicker solution if you have to change a lot of places.

Comment: @tymtam That's a good idea! But still: I have to look up `TypeA` for any values I replace manually. My ideal workflow would be something like this: Change the type of `myType` to `MyEnum` and then *magically* replace any known `int` values to their corresponding enums...

Comment: I am not aware of any such tool, FWIW

Comment: You can try to run a powershell script on your repo, from within VS or outside. Just scan all .cs files, do a pattern matching and replace all occurences. But, is there any int variable that you don't want to replace?

Comment: You could write an C# app that replaces all `\(MyEnum\)[0-9]` with `MyEnum.AppropriateValue`;

Comment: @tymtam I've done exactly that on multiple occasions. The code looks ugly but its still a big improvement!  It is still possible to have an invalid value on the LHS which doesn't map to an actual enum value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Find and replace text tool from the visual studio itself.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019

You have to find and replace the entire solution:

```
(MyEnum) 1 with MyEnum.TypeA 
(MyEnum) 2 with MyEnum.TypeB
```

you just have to check later if there is space in some CS classes.

```
(MyEnum)1 with MyEnum.TypeA 
(MyEnum)2 with MyEnum.TypeB
```

Answer (score 0):

For automating `(MyEnum)2;` `--->` `MyEnum.TypeB`:

### A. Search-and-replace

you could just run a series of 'search and replace' :

1. `\(MyEnum\) 1` to `MyEnum.TypeA`
2. `\(MyEnum\) 2` to `MyEnum.TypeB`
3. (...)

Someone will surely be able to prove a better regex that replaces multiple values in one go.

### B. App

Write a C# app that reads all your files and replaces

```
(MyEnum) number`
```

with something like

```
$"MyEnum.{((MyEnum)number).ToString()}"
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. But, I'm wondering if some VS Extensions already has this kind of feature built-in. I tried creating a Custom Pattern in Resharper, but I think the replace options are too limited for this...